# What is the equivalent of tf.contrib.image.bipartite_match in Tensorflow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Since TensorFlow removed `contrib` library from TF2, anyone has any idea on how to port this particular function?

Comment: Some question, it seems TensorFlow Models contains a [substitute](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/matchers/hungarian_matcher.py), which is 5.x-10.x slow than `tf.contrib.image.bipartite_match` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I need see the log to be able to help you, but try installing "tensorflow_addons"

import tensorflow_addons as tfa

tfa.image..

For more information you can consult https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/transform

Other alternative is use the tf-image. (https://pypi.org/project/tf-image/) or:

from tensorflow.python.ops import image_ops

mage_ops.bipartite_match(distance_matrix, num_valid_rows)

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a custom C++ op following steps at https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op and using the original code at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/1244c8fdda9efb11a5386dce40fbb885f0df190b.
The performance is similar to the TF 1 `tf.contrib.image.bipartite_match`.